# Getting req.file when trying to upload file from React to express js using multer

Tags: node.js, express, backend

I am trying to uploading image file from react to express . The req.body shows the path of image like :- image: 'C:\fakepath\capy1.jpg' but the image cant be accessed using req.file neither its saved in defined location .

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage(
    {
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, 'imageUploads');
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            const uniqueFileName = file.fieldname + Date.now();
            cb(null, uniqueFileName);
        }
    }
)

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/postblog' , upload.single('image'),postController.createPost);
```

```
async function createPost(req, res) {
    try {
        console.log(req.body);

        const { title, summary, description } = req.body;
        console.log(req.file);
        const token = req.cookies.token;

        const decodedData = await jwt.decode(token);

        const blog = new postModel({ title: title, summary: summary, description: description, author: decodedData.username , image : req.file});

        await blog.save();

        console.log(blog);

        return res.status(200).json({ "message": "blog created" });
    }

    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(400);
    }
}
```

```
async function submitPost() {
        
        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('title', post.title);
        formData.append('summary', post.summary);
        formData.append('description', post.description);
        formData.append('image', post.image);

        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
            credentials: 'include'
        }
        console.log(post);
        console.log(formData);
        var response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/postblog', options).catch(error => console.log(error));
        console.log("sent");
        try {
            response = await response.json();
            if (response.status === 200) {
                const data = await response.json();
                console.log(data);
            }
            else {
                alert('Error creating Post');
            }
        }

        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

    }
```

The frontend seems to be working as intentded but i am unable to access the file with req.file . But i am able to access req.body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use single file upload you have to use "file" keyword. if you want to allow multiple files you have to use "files".

```js
/// in your case change "image" to "file"
router.post('/postblog' , upload.single('file'),postController.createPost);
```

examples:

```js
router.post(
    "/update-image",
    upload.single("file"),
    controller_appraisal_modules.avatarUpdate
);

/// how to access the file
exports.avatarUpdate = async(req, res) => {
    const file = req.file;
    console.log(file)
}


router.put(
    "/create",
    // since we specified `array` not `single` we have to use req.files instead of req.file
    // @files   -> key name
    // 2        -> max allowed number of files
    // error response formatted as html
    upload.array("files", 2),
    controller_appraisal_modules.createAPI
);

/// how to access the file
exports.createAPI = async(req, res) => {
    const files = req.files;
    console.log(files)
}
```